# How to use makefile to compile all sources (some only to object files)?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm getting an "undefined reference to main" error on one of my files when trying to compile.  I know this is because this file doesn't have a main method.  This is just an implementation file for some helper methods, so I only want it compiled to an object file not an executable.  I know how to do this if I explicitly tell the makefile what to do for each file, but I'm trying to write a makefile that will compile all of my sources at once. I tried using the `-c` flag, but then it compiled all of my files to only object files rather than executables. How in the world do I do this?
Here it is:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
SRCS = ./src/server.c ./src/client_slave.c ./src/sockaddrAL.c
EXECS = ./bin/server ./bin/client_slave
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: clean $(SRCS) server client

server: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ./src/server.o -o ./bin/server

client: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ./src/client_slave.o -o ./bin/client_slave

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
        @rm -f $(EXECS) $(OBJS)
```

Comment: The sample Makefile you post looks like it should work just fine.  Does it not?

Comment: For future reference, do not edit your makefile with stuff you got from answers after you got help. Those coming into this thread will be confused as to why you have a "-c" option yet someone suggests it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the `-c` flag to the rule that builds `.o` files (your `.c.o` suffix rule) and *not* add it to the rule that builds the executables (the `$(EXECS)` rule).

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
EXECS = ./bin/server ./bin/client_slave

all: $(EXECS)

./bin/%: ./src/%.o ./src/sockaddrAL.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
        @rm -f $(EXECS) $(OBJS)
```

You didn't show sockAddrAL at all in your question so I assumed it belonged in both executables.  Also note that the above syntax assumes GNU `make`.  If you want to use only features available in POSIX standard `make` you pretty much have to write it all out.

Comment: Okay, this fixes that issue, but now I'm having another issue because I have a main method in client_slave.c  Is there a way to have this compile both executables at once using a makefile like this?

Comment: Sorry, you haven't given enough information for me to show a makefile.  Presumably some of your files are supposed to be used to build a `server` program and others are supposed to be used to build a `client` program.  You need to create two different rules for the link step: one that links the `server` program with the `.o` files that go into the `server` program, and the other that links the `client` program with the `.o` files that go into the `client` program.  There's no way `make` can figure out that's what you want :-)

Comment: I updated the makefile in the OP.  This is what I want to do (and this makefile works), but was looking for a more elegant/streamlined way of doing it.

Comment: Your makefile is not right.  You should never create a rule with a target like `server` that actually creates a file with a different name, like `./bin/server`.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This works, but is there any way to do this but still be able to type `make server` rather than needing `make bin/server` ?

Comment: Yes, you need to define a new rule `server : ./bin/server` (no recipe is needed).  Likely you also want to also add `.PHONY: server` which, at least for GNU make, will ensure that a local file or directory named `server` won't disrupt your makefile (and it's innocuous in non-GNU versions of make).

Answer (score 1):

Let implicit rules be your friend.  Your entire Makfefile should just be:

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -O0 -g -Wall
SRCS = server.c client_slave.c sockaddrAL.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
EXECS = server

server: $(OBJS)

clean:
    @rm -f $(EXECS) $(OBJS)
```

Invoke it from the src directory.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still kind of noobish with creating makefiles.  I see that that will complete objects rule (.c files to .o files), but how does it know how to compile to the binary if you're not using $(CC) or $(CFLAGS)?

Comment: `make` has a large dictionary of built-in rules it can apply if none of the rules in your makefile match.  To see it, run `make -pf/dev/null`.  One of these rules describes how to build an executable from a `.o` with the same prefix (so if your main file was `server_main.c` this would not work) plus any other prerequisites you specified.